# Split in a Load Bearing Stud

Tags: studs

How do I fix a split at the bottom of a load bearing 2x4 stud? The split is in the king stud for a window. It's a 9 in. long triangular shaped piece. It's 1/4 in. deep at the sole plate and expands to 1 in. at the top of the triangle. The piece is 5/8 in. wide on the narrow side of the stud. The stud next to it is ~5 in. away, so it's a tight space. Do I need to fix it? If so, what's the best way?

Sorry the pics not so great. The sole plate and bottom of the stud are in a "pocket" formed by the raised floor. I smeared the crack with Liquid Nails. There's also spray foam in the bottom of the pic, so it looks like a mess.I added arrows along the path of the crack. It split when I put the (now bent) nail in.

[image]

Comment: A photo would help. I can't imagine how a stud with weight on it could separate so catastrophically like you describe. Are you saying that there's a one inch void in the middle of your stud?

Comment: @isherwood I added a photo and description. The stud is 50 yrs old and dry, and I split it when I put the nail in.

Comment: "Deep" and "expands" aren't words I'd have used to describe that. You have a simple crack, and the king stud isn't any more load-bearing than a common stud, and the crack doesn't substantially weaken the wall. The trimmer next to it carries the header. This isn't a concern.

Answer (score 2):

If you are concerned about it and have access to it (which you apparently do since you can see the split), just sister another stud onto the side of it.

This will share its load without the need to remove it. It should be fine even if it is in a load bearing wall.

Good luck!

Comment: Do I need to sister it along the stud's full length or can I sister it along 3 ft or so at the bottom. I can see the stud. But, the floor is raised, so accessing  the sole plate is difficult. So, it won't be easy to sister it along its full length.

Comment: If you're worried, scab on as much as you can conveniently fit with construction adhesive and screws. It's really not an issue, though.

Comment: If you can't sister along the full length, you can't share the load but, as Isherwood said you can scab on a piece of 2x4 that will add strength to the split one. A split like that doesn't affect the studs vertical load capability that much especially since the stud is held together by the inside and outside walls. I would agree it is not really a structural issue so it doesn't need to be removed and replaced. More of an OCD issue. I understand though I have that too. 